# SQLエディターで作成したパラメータを削除または全てを対象にする方法

Tags: .net, sql

VisualStudioにてクエリビルダーのエディターを利用してパラメータを設定した場合、
**@コード**をWHERE句から除外するか全てを対象にする方法はありますでしょうか。

```
SELECT  コード,単価
FROM    商品マスタ
WHERE   コード=@コード
```

SqlDataSourceのSelectQueryに対して
SqlCommandのcommand.Parameters.Addと同様の機能が使えればと思ったのですが
現在は以下のようなSQL文で対応しております。

```
SELECT  コード,単価
FROM    商品マスタ
WHERE   (@コード IS NULL OR [コード] = @コード)
```

Comment: いまいち現在のSQL文に対して何が不満で、この質問で何を求めているのかわかりませんでした。

Comment: わかりづらい文書ですみません。where句を動的に追加できるか。という質問の方が正しい表現だったと思います。

Answer (score 1):

SQL文は文字列なので動的に変更することは可能ですが、その場合、何等かのフレームワークを用いるのも１つの手です。
例えば.NET Frameworkには[Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb399567(v=vs.110).aspx)が提供されています。これを使用すると.NETコードで動的にSQL文を構築できます。またSqlDataSourceに相当する[EntityDataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource(v=vs.110).aspx)も提供されています。（こちらは使ったことがないので適切かどうかはわかりませんが…）

これらを使ったとしても内部的には質問者さんの書かれたようなSQL文が生成されてDBエンジン上で実行されることには変わりありません。

Comment: 丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。EntityFrameWorkについては勉強してみます。動的に作るにはSqlDataAdapterからプログラムで作り込むしかなさそうです。ツールボックスのオブジェクトへ簡単にParameters.Clear()やParameter.AddWithValueできるかと思ったのですが、無理そうでした。回答にお時間頂き感謝致します。

Answer (score 0):

ストアドプロシージャ(T-SQL)を利用すれば動的なSQLが書けることがわかりましたが、
以下のSQL文の方が優れているように思いますし、複雑なコードが不要となると思います。

```
WHERE   (@コード IS NULL OR [コード] = @コード)
```

T-SQLで動的に行う場合は以下で分岐が可能でした。

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ado].[item]
@コード nvarchar(30)

IF @コード IS NULL
  BEGIN
  SELECT  コード,単価
  FROM    商品マスタ
  END

ELSE    
  BEGIN
  SELECT  コード,単価
  FROM    商品マスタ
  WHERE   コード=@コード
  END
```